# Cutting some specific lines from a text and putting them into another file

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have a text file which contains lines. I want to cut the lines whose number is in the list, and put them into another file.

For instance, if I have a list which contains `[1, 3, 67]`, then I want to put the line number 1, the line number 3 and the line number 67 into a new file, and remove them from the original file. What is the easiest way to do that in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea in case you don't want to keep all lines in memory:

```
def lines(fname, numbers):
    numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
    with open(fname) as f:
        for n, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if n == numbers[-1]:
                yield line
                numbers.pop()
                if not numbers:
                     break
```

Links to docs:

- [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)
- [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

**EDIT:** if you're okay with reading the whole file at once (and want to return a list of lines), you can use `readlines()` to get a list of all lines, but to me it doesn't make sense anyway, so I'd do what I showed above. However, you can do:

```
def lines(fname, numbers):
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return [lines[i] for i in numbers]
```

Change `lines[i]` to `lines[i+1]` if you want "natural" numbering.

**Edit2:** Then you still need to write **two** new files: one with these lines and one with the rest of the lines. To do it, `open` files and use the file object's [`writelines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) method.

Comment: Since you are going for a generator oriented implementation, I think `izip` would be better?

Comment: @LevLevitsky it is not a problem to keep all lines in memory for me, since there is not a very large number, can you also provide another version of your code in this case please ? thanks

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma Good point, thanks. I forgot `zip` returned a list because I try to use Python 3 if possible. `itertools.izip` doesn't exist on Python 3, because `zip` does what `izip` does on Python 2.

Comment: Wouldn't `for n, line in enumerate(f, 1):` be simpler, and work in both Python 2 and Python 3?

Comment: there is an indentation problem at if n == number[-1]

Comment: @shn Fixed the indentation, sorry.

Comment: However this doesn't remove the concerned lines from the original file !

Comment: Well how do you remove the extracted ( [lines[i] for i in numbers] ) lines from lines to write it to a new file

Comment: @shn I added a hint about it in the end.

Comment: "rest of the lines" it is not clear how to have the rest of the lines

Comment: @shn You'll need to modify the `lines` function a little so that it returns all lines except for the numbers given. In the first sample you'll need change the `for` loop's body; in the second example you can use list's [`pop`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) method in a loop to remove the unneeded lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.islice()`:

For example if the file is :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

code:

```
In [107]: li=[2,4,6]  # this list should be sorted first
In [108]: with open("abc.txt") as f:
    prev=0
    for num in li:
        print list(islice(f,num-prev-1,num-prev))       
        prev=num
   .....:         
['2\n']
['4\n']
['6\n']

In [109]: li=[1,7,9]

In [110]: with open("abc.txt") as f:
    prev=0
    for num in li:
        print list(islice(f,num-prev-1,num-prev))  #print or do something else     
        prev=num
   .....:         
['1\n']
['7\n']
['9\n']
```